# What is the performance cost of a Win32 process switch?

Tags: windows, winapi, operating-system, kernel

I know the cost of a physical Win32 thread context switch is estimated at between 2-8k cycles. Any estimates on the cost of a process switch?

Comment: What do you think the process switch is?

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov: thread context switch != process context switch. The thread context switch just requires to change the stack pointer and some changes in the system structures , while a full process context switch implies also the reprogramming of the MMU and more changes in the system structures.

Comment: @Matteo, you assume that the switch is to a thread of the same process, while the scheduler is free to pick a thread from a different one.

Comment: I know that a process switch *implies* a thread switch (or, if you prefer, a thread switch to a thread of another process triggers also a process switch), but since he's asking the different costs of them I supposed he was asking about a "pure" thread switch (thread switch to another thread of the same process) vs a thread switch + process switch.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking for estimates, I'd test it. Start with a program like:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() { 
    for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
        Sleep(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Then create a parent program that spawns (say) 32 copies of this, and then uses `WaitForMultipleObjects` to wait for them to all finish. Measure the (wall) time from start to finish, and divide by the total number of process switches. Of course, you want to run on a relatively quiescent system to get a meaningful result.

Comment: Sleep(0) does not always cause a context switch.  Especially not on a quiescent system as you suggest.  Read the docs: "A value of zero causes the thread to relinquish the remainder of its time slice to any other thread that is ready to run. If there are no other threads ready to run, the function returns immediately, and the thread continues execution." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A quote from "[Windows Internals 5Ed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735625301)":

> Windows must determine which thread
>   should run next. When Windows selects
>   a new thread to run, it performs a
>   context switch to it. A context switch
>   is the procedure of saving the
>   volatile machine state associated with
>   a running thread, loading another
>   thread’s volatile state, and starting
>   the new thread’s execution.
>
> Windows schedules at the thread
>   granularity. This approach makes sense
>   when you consider that processes don’t
>   run but only provide resources and a
>   context in which their threads run.
>   Because scheduling decisions are made
>   strictly on a thread basis, no
>   consideration is given to what process
>   the thread belongs to. For example, if
>   process A has 10 runnable threads,
>   process B has 2 runnable threads, and
>   all 12 threads are at the same
>   priority, each thread would
>   theoretically receive one-twelfth of
>   the CPU time—Windows wouldn’t give 50
>   percent of the CPU to process A and 50
>   percent to process B.
>
> ...
>
> A thread’s context and the procedure
>   for context switching vary depending
>   on the processor’s architecture. A
>   typical context switch requires saving
>   and reloading the following data: A.
>   Instruction pointer B. Kernel stack
>   pointer C. A pointer to the address
>   space in which the thread runs (the
>   process’s page table directory). The
>   kernel saves this information from the
>   old thread by pushing it onto the
>   current (old thread’s) kernel-mode
>   stack, updating the stack pointer, and
>   saving the stack pointer in the old
>   thread’s KTHREAD block. The kernel
>   stack pointer is then set to the new
>   thread’s kernel stack, and the new
>   thread’s context is loaded. **If the new
>   thread is in a different process, it
>   loads the address of its page table
>   directory into a special processor
>   register so that its address space is
>   available.** 
>   Control passes to the new thread’s
>   restored instruction pointer and the
>   new thread resumes execution.

So the only overhead for thread-context switch to another process is as minimal as setting the value of one processor register - totally negligible.

Comment: I think you are misreading that.  At the very least, a full pre-emptive context switch requires saving the entire "user" processor state which includes all the user registers.  The part you highlighted only has to do with the stack register and changing stacks but you still need to preserve registers.